# Blender export support for 3MF (or AMF) file format?

Tags: export

As I am preparing some design to be printed on a full colour 3D-printer, I ran into the 3MF file format as a possible format supporting colour better than .STL.

see: http://www.3mf.io/what-is-3mf/,
see: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583998/info-about-3mf-file-format-for-3d-printing)

On the website there is also a link to an "Open Source Library": https://github.com/3mfconsortium, I didn't go into details (and I didn't check the Microsoft side (is their Open Source same as ours?)), but support for export to this format from Blender would be nice, i.m.h.o.

What about support from Blender to export in 3MF ? Can somebody shed light on this?

Thanks for reading and responding in advance!
Regards,
Wim.

Comment: Only thing I could find http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?382248-standalone-Python-Microsoft-3mf-to-Blender-usable-ply

Comment: Hi Duarte, Yes, I saw that one, but I run into the same error as the person who replied on this, it complaints on "colorid".

Answer (score 3):

This is a tough one. My concern about most of the answers that I see on the Blender forums is that people don't get that 3MF is NOT like STL, it allows for actual bitmaps for textures, not just one flat color.

So, I do have a workflow for you, that will at least get your model out, if you are running Windows 10.

Setup Blender to export to GLTF. Export a binary GLTF (GLB).

Open the Windows 3D builder app. It's free.

Open the GLTF with 3D Builder.

Then export a 3MF.

I tested it with Simplify3D and it seemed to work fine. The model sliced fairly easily.

```
    == John ==
```